# SVG draws lines with different thickness

Tags: svg

I'm trying to draw multiple lines on the screen, but for some reason the third line gets drawn thicker than the rest even though I have specified the same thickness for each element:

```
<svg height="210" width="500" style="margin-left:100px;margin-top:100px;">
  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="0" style="stroke:rgb(50, 50, 50);stroke-width:1" />
  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="200" style="stroke:rgb(50, 50, 50);stroke-width:1" />
  <line x1="0" y1="200" x2="200" y2="200" style="stroke:rgb(50, 50, 50);stroke-width:1" />
</svg>
```

[The weird result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvU7k.png)

If I remove the first two lines, the third line still gives the weird thickness issue, I noticed that if I set y2 to 0 for the third line, the line thickness disappears, but if it's set, then it stays thick, even though it's not rotated. I can't seem to find any information on this issue, this occurs on both - Chrome and Firefox. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55338765/why-same-thickness-lines-in-grid-show-different-thickness

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57748455/drawing-lines-with-the-same-stroke-size-produces-lines-of-different-thickness

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because half of the stroke-width of each of your first two lines are getting cut off because they're not in the view (i.e. 1/2 px width is < 0).  You can see this fixed by adjusting the image slightly to:

`<svg height="210" width="500" style="margin-left:100px;margin-top:100px;">
  <line x1="0" y1="1" x2="200" y2="1" style="stroke:rgb(50, 50, 50);stroke-width:1" />
  <line x1="1" y1="0" x2="1" y2="200" style="stroke:rgb(50, 50, 50);stroke-width:1" />
  <line x1="0" y1="200" x2="200" y2="200" style="stroke:rgb(50, 50, 50);stroke-width:1" />
</svg>`

https://jsfiddle.net/uax2zj7g/