# Why same thickness Lines in Grid show different thickness?

Tags: wpf, xaml, window

I have a problem with line's thickness,And I can't figure out what's the reason.
I have a stackPanel in which I put in 2 Grid.In each grid,I have two line with same thickness. Code is Here:

```
 <StackPanel Width="300" Margin="10" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="LightGray">
        <Grid>
            <Line X1="0" Y1="0" X2="200" Y2="0" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1"/>
            <Line X1="0" Y1="24" X2="200" Y2="24" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Line X1="0" Y1="0" X2="200" Y2="0" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1"/>
            <Line X1="0" Y1="24" X2="200" Y2="24" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
```

and when I run the app, I found weird things like this:
[image]
I'm wondering why the lines show different thickness.

Comment: You may set `UseLayoutRounding="False"` and `RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"` to avoid anti-aliasing and layout rounding effects.

Comment: Also, `SnapsToDevicePixels="True"` can help with that as well.

Comment: @Clemens your comment really works.I will research deep in what you mentioned.Thanks!