# Drawing lines with the same stroke size produces lines of different thickness

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have the following custom view that draws two lines one below another:

```
class GridView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private val linePaint = Paint()

    init {
        linePaint.color = Color.DKGRAY
        linePaint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        linePaint.strokeWidth = 50f //resources.getDimension(R.dimen.line_width)
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)

        canvas.drawLine(0f, 0f, width.toFloat(), 0f, linePaint)

        canvas.drawLine(0f, 200f, width.toFloat(), 200f, linePaint)
    }

}
```

The view has a fixed size:

```
   <com.vgrec.playground.tictactoe.GridView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp" />
```

and the result looks like this:

[image]

Any ideas why the second line is thicker than the first one, although they both use the same stroke size of `50f`?

Comment: The drawn line is centered on the line segment defined by the coordinates you pass in the `drawLine()` method. That is, half of the stroke width is on either side of it. When you draw that line at the very top of the `View`, the upper half of the stroke is out of bounds.

Comment: Ahh, I see, nice explanation! Thank you.